# API for delete function is not working anymore and doesn't remove anything from array?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, mongoose

When i try to remove one post from view apparently shows that it is removed. However when i go back in providers route i can find all the previous member of array through below route . However when i am in route of /posts doesn't show me previous removed members. Interesting it is that after refreshing page it doesn't show me record on my view anymore. 
In following route, post disappear while i try it from command prompt :

**/providers/553b72c9f6d0020425d37f37/posts**

```
router.get('/providers/:provider/posts', function(req, res) {  Provider.findById(req.params.provider).select('posts').populate('posts').exec(function(err, provider) {
        if(err){ return next(err); }
        res.json(provider.posts);
    });
});
```

However in this route, i can find posts array with 9 member. It seems that any of the removed doesn't work.

```
router.get('/providers', function(req, res, next) {
    Provider.find(function(err, providers){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(providers);
    });
});
```

Here is my remove function in server side:

```
router.delete('/providers/:provider/posts/:post',auth, function(req, res){
    console.log("I ma running from server")
    return Post.findById(req.params.post, function(err, post){
        return post.remove(function(err){
            if(!err){
                Post.update({_id: post.provider}, {$pull : {posts : post._id}}, function(err, numberAffected){
                    console.log(numberAffected);
                    if(!err){
                        return console.log('removed post id');
                    } else {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                });
                console.log('post removed');
                return res.send('');
            } else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here what i have inside my factory in client side:

```
 ob.deletePost = function (provider_id,post_id) {
        return $http.delete(urlBase +'/providers/' + provider_id +'/posts/' + post_id ,
            {
            headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
        });
    };
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.deletePost= function (provider_id,post_id) {
        //console.log('PROVIDER',provider_id);
        // console.log('POST',post_id);
        // console.log('COMMENT',comment_id);

        providers.deletePost(provider_id,post_id)

            .success(function () {
                $scope.status = 'Deleted Post! Refreshing post list.';

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.provider.posts.length; i++) {
                    var post = $scope.provider.posts[i];
                    // console.log(i,comment,comment_id)
                    //console.log(comment.ID);
                    if (post._id === post_id) {
                        //console.log(provider._id === provider_id)
                        // console.log(provider._id);
                        $scope.provider.posts.splice(i, 1);
                        //providers.getAllComments();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // $scope.providers = null; // i am not sure how to write  for comment as well?

            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to delete comment: ' + error.message;
            });
    };
```

And here is one part of my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="provider in providers"> <!-- | orderBy:'-upvotes'-->
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
              ng-click="incrementUpvotes(provider)"></span>
        <span style="font-size:18px; margin-left:10px;">
                {{provider.upvotes}} - <strong>{{provider.name}}</strong>
          <span ng-if="provider.posts.length !== 0">
                <a ui-sref="post({provider_id : provider._id})">{{provider.posts.length}} Posts </a>
              <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right"  ng-click="modalUpdateProvider('size',provider)">Edit</button>
          </span>
```

Never **provider.posts.length** is updating. For watching **provider and post views** you can review following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855111/how-query-api-to-get-all-the-data-for-third-level-of-path).
Thank you.

Comment: You delete the a post on the server side, but you don't update the provider(s) on the client side. You have to reload the providers or remove the post manually.

Comment: @michael, I updated new one. i did that inside controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong model in your update statement:

```
router.delete('/providers/:provider/posts/:post', auth, function(req, res) {
  console.log("I ma running from server");
  // NOTE: you could also include a where clause to ensure the 
  // provider ID matches as well. This would prevent someone from using any
  // provider ID (inclduing one that doesn't exist) with a post ID.
  return Post.findById(req.params.post, function(err, post) {
    // Might want to check for an error here
    console.log('post removed');

    return post.remove(function(err) {
      if (!err) {
        //Post.update({
        Provider.update({
          _id: post.provider // or req.params.provider
        }, {
          $pull: {
            posts: post._id
          }
        }, function(err, numberAffected) {
          console.log(numberAffected);
          if (!err) {
            console.log('removed post id');
          } else {
            console.log(err);
          }
          return res.send('');
        });
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also, you could use the findByIdAndXXX methods as well as the built in promises to chain these together for easier readability:

```
router.delete('/providers/:provider/posts/:post', auth, function(req, res) {
  console.log("I ma running from server");
  // NOTE: you could also include a where clause to ensure the 
  // provider ID matches as well. This would prevent someone from using any
  // provider ID (inclduing one that doesn't exist) with a post ID.
  return Post.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.post).exec().then(function(post) {
    console.log('post removed');
    return Provider.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.provider, {
        $pull: {
          posts: post._id
        }
      }, {
        new: true
      } // Return updated document
    ).exec(); // return promise to be evaluated for next handler
  }).then(function(provider) {
    console.log('removed post id');
    res.send('');
  }).then(null, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    //might want to send a response error here
  });
});
```

Update: to use a where clause you will need to switch to findOneAndXXX methods:

```
router.delete('/providers/:provider/posts/:post', auth, function(req, res) {
  console.log("I am running from server");
  return Post.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.post, provider_id: req.params.provider}).exec().then(function(post) {
    console.log('post removed');
    return Provider.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.provider, {
        $pull: {
          posts: post._id // or req.params.post
        }
      }, {
        new: true
      } // Return updated document
    ).exec(); // return promise to be evaluated for next handler
  }).then(function(provider) {
    console.log('removed post id');
    res.send('');
  }).then(null, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    //might want to send a response error here
  });
});
```

Comment: Updated answer to show how to do it within the query.

Comment: so , u mean from where clause only using findOneAndRemove? As i can not see more difference with previous one. I'm just thinking u mean conditional statement.

Comment: Mongoose internally converts the conditional object into a where clause for mongoDB.